# What is iOS UIScrollView's equivalent to Android's OnDraw(Canvas canvas)?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uiscrollview, scrollview, draw

I'm trying to write the iOS equivalent of my Android code for a **ScrollViewRenderer**.

In Android I have the following method which is called each time the scrollview is scrolled, allowing me to update the UI:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    ...
    ...
    base.OnDraw(canvas);
}
```

In iOS I'm trying to do the same thing with the following method. However it is only called when the page loads and not upon each scroll event:

```
public override void Draw(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
{
    ...
    ...
    base.Draw(rect);
}
```

I have a few questions:

- What is the iOS equivalent method I should be using instead of **Draw**?
- Will this method provide me with a canvas to draw on? I want to display a scrolling bitmap, but can't do much with just a CGRect.
- How can I get the current **ScrollY**? In Android this is a Property of the Renderer class. I can't find it in iOS.

Comment: I don't recall what iOS class is used by X-Forms ScrollViewRenderer - can you see what iOS class the renderer's `Control` is? That determines what properties and methods exist.

Comment: There is no `Control` as such, but `ScrollViewRenderer` is itself derived from `UIScrollView`.

Comment: ok good. Then your question becomes: "What is UIScrollView's equivalent to Xamarin.Android ScrollViewRenderer's `OnDraw` method?" Sorry I'm not familiar with that, but hopefully `UIScrollView` is a topic that more people are familiar with. Added that tag.

Comment: Makes sense, I will search in that direction. Thanks.

Comment: Been reading further but so far haven't come up with anything helpful. I'm thinking of catching the `Scrolled` event and calling `SetNeedsDisplay();`. This seems to trigger `OnDraw` successfully, but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution. As such wondering if you think it is sound, or you can foresee problems with this.

Comment: Seems reasonable, though may make scroll "jerky" on low-end devices. (I think that event is called repeatedly during a scroll.) If that is a problem, let me know. I'll show you how to write code that triggers an action (the redraw via SetNeedsDisplay) a half-second in the future, but keeps delaying that action until no trigger event (scrolled) happens for a full half-second. This would update display half-second after user stops scrolling.

Comment: Sure, will let you know, thanks